# What are the easiest mountain peaks in Alps that does not require rope/climbing/scrambling?

Tags: europe, hiking, mountains

Next summer I wonder if there are any mountain peaks starting at 1500 meters and up to 2500 (to avoid oxygen problems beyond that), for average fitness person who is not an experienced mountaineer, does not know how to climb and just wants to get a great view from the top. Also, no good with ridges.

A rather easy walk uphill that is, up to 2500, with mountain hut accommodation, in the Alps? Any suggestions?

Comment: There are almost an uncountable number of family-friendly mountain peaks in that range and area you are talking about. Just in South Germany, you will probably find several hundred mountains matching your requirements.

Comment: You might not need _supplemental_ oxygen at 3000m, but you will certainly notice the difference, and some people _do_ need it at that altitude.

Comment: Hi Tor Einar, from your name I assume you are Scandinavian. You know any family friendly peaks in Norway, then in Sweden? I will visit both the Alps and Norway next summer. Thanks

Comment: @Michael Hampton. Therefore any peaks up to 2500 I guess would be ok. Thanks again. I dont aim to be per se a mountaineer. I just like the uphill challenge. I have a problem though with ridges and any situation that is having me look down in the void (narrow ridges etc). I am guessing some peaks do not involve scrambling, climbing, or ridge walking. Im looking for easy ones but still magnificent and great to top/visit.

Answer (score 3):

If you want both the highest and the easiest, that must be Pic d'Artinsol. It's just a hair below 3000m, the official height I believe is 2997m. But there's a chair lift to 2121m and the summit is a very easy walk from there.